# Socket IO control in .NET Core for DSCP

Tags: .net-core, network-programming, ip, winsock2, qos

.NET Core provides `Sockets` class which is an implementation of Berkely Sockets API.

It provides a method [IOControl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket.iocontrol?view=netcore-2.2) that allows setting low-level IO Control. It also has an enum where we can use `IOControlCode.SetQos`. What should be the value of other parameters of this method if we want to set DSCP of the IP header to CS1 (0x08) ?

The documentation says it passes the value to internal WinSockApi's `WSAIoctl` method. However its documentation is difficult to comprehend.

Comment: It is [a DWORD option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/WinSock/ip-dscp-traffic-type), equivalent to uint in C#.  Use BitConverter.GetBytes(8) to generate the optionInValue parameter value, null for the outValue.  Do beware it silently ignored if the policy isn't turned on by the machine admin, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/networking/technologies/qos/qos-policy-manage

Comment: I understand the format, I am looking for detailed value or example. if that is in c++ I can translate to .net

Comment: A detailed 8?  If you want somebody to write and test the code for you then you need to say so in your question.